Error This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7275/ HTTP ERROR 404 al crear un API
en la actulidad llevamos un buen tiempo tratando de hacer un codigo funcional que nos permita obtener lo que deseamos. En este punto de nuestro desarrollo, ya logramos hacer la conexion para consumir un servico API REST, luego de ello, hemos creado unos metodos que nos permitan insertar los datos a una tabla en nuestra base de datos SQL Server.
En este punto, cuando compilamos el codigo para ver los resultados en swagger y ejecutar los metodos, nos parece el siguiente error en nuestro navegador:
This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7275/
HTTP ERROR 404

No tenemos claridad del funcionamiento de C# para generar la url, pues ya le hicimos la conexion a la base detos y pensabamos que eso era todo para finalizar.
Indagando un poco en nuestro codigo que se encuentra dentro de un proyecto tipo web Model-View-Controller, encontramos un archivo denominado launchSettings.json.
En este archivo, identificamos algunas conexiones y url que el sistema a generado automaticamente y esta usando actualmente, las cuales son:
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:26071",
      "sslPort": 44382
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "BIL2": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7275;http://localhost:5145",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}

En este punto, se puede ver claramente dos url las cuales son:
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7275;http://localhost:5145",
Agradecemos las observaciones que puedan brindarnos para continuar avanzando en este desarrollo.
